# GLM missing data

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, missing-data

I've come across the problem of missing data when doing GLMs. I'm using GLMs to make predictions in R. My dependent variable is continuous and my independent variables are factors. The question arises, what to do with NA values in the factor variables.

What I've been doing in the past was making a separate factor level for NA and then combining it with another factor with a similar GLM coefficient. But as I've read, that can lead to biased results. Also what worries me is, what if the data with the NA values in some variable should all in reality be in the lowest or highest level? Then I discard additional information, and make predictions too high or too low, right?

A possibility a colleague suggested was discarding all the data with NA values. But that way I might lose way too much data.

What is the recommended way to deal with missing data in this case? I've read about imputation, but it seems to me as if that's going to lead to me making some variables significant when they are not (I'm already manually grouping similar ones together).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Much depends on the reasons why data are missing. There are 3 commonly cited missingness mechanisms, missing completely at random (MCAR), missing at random (MAR) and missing not at random (MNAR).

MCAR means that missing values occur randomly in that variable without any dependence on any other variable, observed or not.

MAR means that missing values occur randomly in that variable but the probability of being missing depends on values of one or more other observed variables (which might include your outcome variable).

If missingness depends on unobserved variables then the data are missing not at random (MNAR).

Deleting observations with missing data (known as complete-case analysis or listwise deletion), is a bad idea at the very least because it discards information which results in larger standard errors, wider confidence intervals and loss of power. Under MCAR the estimates will be unbiased, but under MAR they may be biased:

> Complete Case analysis confines attention to cases where all  variables are present. Advantages of this approach are .... . Disadvantages stem from the potential loss of information in discarding incomplete cases. This loss of information has two aspects: loss of precision, and **bias when the missing-data mechanism is not MCAR**, and the complete cases are not a random sample of all the cases".

From:  Statistical Analysis with Missing Data, Second Edition, Roderick J.A. Little & Donald B Rubin, John Wiley and Sons, 2002. p41:
http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/9781119013563

Creating a factor/indicator/dummy variable for missingness is also a biased method, for example see:

White IR, Carlin JB. Bias and efficiency of multiple imputation compared with
complete-case analysis for missing covariate values. Stat Med 2010;29:2920-31.
http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/sim.3944

Jones MP. Indicator and stratification methods for missing explanatory variables in multiple linear regression. J Am Stat Assoc 1996;91:222-30.
http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/01621459.1996.10476680

If the data are plausibly MAR or MCAR then multiple imputation will yield unbiased estimates when applied correctly and standard errors will be smaller than with complete-case analysis. If missingness depends on unobserved variables then the data are missing not at random (MNAR) and this is much more difficult to handle.

Multiple imputation works by filling in missing values with plausible values from a model. This is done multiple times and each time the imputed values will differ to allow for uncertainty. The analysis model is run on each imputed dataset and the results are pooled. In essence, the method works because, on the one hand, while it is possible to estimate the most likely values for the missing data, the most likely values are in fact unlikely to be the correct values: there is inherent uncertainty. The variability in the values which are imputed between each completed dataset provides the uncertainty which is needed to reflect the uncertainty created by the missing values.

`MICE` is an excellent package for R which implements multiple imputation.
https://www.jstatsoft.org/index.php/jss/article/view/v045i03/v45i03.pdf

**Update:**
Examples on how to handle missing values in r using the imputation methods and `MICE`packages:
https://uvastatlab.github.io/2019/05/01/getting-started-with-multiple-imputation-in-r/

Comment: What exactely do you mean by "can yield"? That it usually yields unbiased results, or that it can sometimes yield unbiased results, but more often it doesn't?

Also, is the method I am currently using bad, or is it a reasonable way to taclke this problem, just not as accurate as multiple imputation?

Comment: @gregorp I have updated the answer to address your comment.

Comment: So I've tried the MICE package. I made a glm model on all data. Then I deleted the first 10% observations for a variable and did a multiple imputation. Unfortunately the results of the multiple imputation seem to be more far off from the orinigal model, than if I make a dummy variable for these 10%. What could be the cause of that? Am I using the imputation wrong, or can such a thing happen?

Comment: @gregorp  why did you delete 10% of the observations for a variable before doing multiple imputation ? If you are going to use MI you shouldn't be deleting anything. When you say the results are "more far off" than the original model, what was the original model ? In what way are the different ? The results can certainly be different with MI, because listwise deletion and making a dummy variable are biased methods. How many imputation and iterations did you use ? Did you check that convergence had been achieved ?

Comment: I'm sorry my comment was unclear. I wanted to see how MI is doing on an example so I made a glm1 with one variable without missing data. Then I deleted 10% of the data and did glm2 with MI and glm3 with a dummy variable for comparison. The coefficients of glm3 were closer to coefficients of glm1. But at that point I used 50 imputations and 5 iterations. Later I've left the PC running and tried with 50 imputations and the results of MI seem better, but still not in all coefficients. How many iterations are usually enough for a good model?

Comment: @gregorp 50 imputations and 50 iterations should be more than enough - but did you actually check convergence ?

Please post a reproducible example with data (simulated if you like) and code in another question so that we can look at this, since this is now beyond the scope of the current question.

Comment: I haven't checked for convergence as I haven't learned yet how to do it. Is there a function for it? I'll try to make a reproducible example and let you know.

Comment: @gregorp yes, you simply run `plot()` on the object returned by the `mice()` function. At this point I'd also recommend reading some of the online tutorials such as [this one](http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~dwarton/missingDataLab.html)

Comment: Ok, I'll run the plot() command, when R Studio is finished doing another imputation (takes some time), thank you. One more question. If you make a model, then delete some data, impute the deleted data and make a model based on those imputations, the results of the both models should be very similar right?

Comment: @gregorp it depends on how you delete the data. It would really be better if you asked a new question and provided a reproducible example.

Comment: I guess the problem was with how I was deleting the data. I deleted the first 10%, since I thought the data was ordered randomly. Tried another example where I deleted the data randomly and MI gives much better results than the dummy variable method in every parameter. Thank you for all your help! I also checked for convergence, seems that it converged.